# What does “spizando” mean?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, verbs, adjectives, vocabulary

Although I am also learning Italian (so please feel free to answer in Italian, it will help me learn) I encountered this word in a different context: a musical score.

In the second movement of Boulez’ first sonata he writes “molto spizando” as an indication how a specific bar should be played.

[image: relevant excerpt of the Boulez]

I checked all the dictionaries I could get my hands on (some very respectable musical dictionaries but also Treccani among others) but the closest word I can find is the verb “spizzicare”. To my knowledge there is no way to form “spizando” from spizzicare, only “spizzicando”. A form of spizzicare would also be unexpected in this context.

Does this word exist at all or did Boulez invent it for this sonata?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Interesting. If anything, it might be related (up to one _z_ rather than two) with the verb [_spizzare_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spizzare), which is not used in all of Italy. Do you happen to have any idea, by some other way, of what Boulez meant?

Comment: Or a mistype for _spaziando_...?

Comment: Ooh, that could be! The definition is very specific to card games though... I never found it since it’s at the other end of the spiz- words (spiza- to spizz-). It might be a misspelling of Boulez; he was French and although he was a very knowledgeable man it could be that he didn’t really know the language at all. This kind of mistake certainly occurs in scores of other composers. (But Boulez is incredibly precise so a simple misspelling would be slightly out of character.)

Comment: @DaG I don’t think a typo by Boulez is probable, since the original score was handwritten. The edition might be off though, although this would be a particularly egregious example. I’ll compare with a different edition tomorrow!

Comment: @DaG: According to [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000895.jpg), "spizare" is an archaic form of "spicciare".

Comment: One of the meanings (from GDLI) of "spicciare" (also archaic) is "staccare; spiccare".

Comment: @Charo What a find! An archaic form seems a much better fit for Boulez than a spelling error. I'm reading through the various meanings of spicciare to see how I can apply it to this music. So far definition 5 (articolare, pronunciare a stento) seems the most appropriate (considering the register of the notes to be played molto spizando). 10 would be the funniest. For future readers, a direct link to the definitions continuing on [the next page](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000896.jpg).

Comment: Definitions 18 ("risonare (un suono, una voce)") and 20 ("spiccare, risaltare per contrasto con quanto è intorno") are also very possible. I wish I could ask Mr. Boulez...

Comment: What is the intended instrument(s) for this score? Maybe that "spizando" should be instead "pizzicando"?

Comment: Another very remote possibility could be a back-formation from French *épicer*, "to add spices". *ép* -> *sp* and *c* -> *z* are common substitutions to get an Italian word from a French one.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Piano solo. I suppose pizzicando would mean to pluck the strings and that is very impractical on a piano already, but here simply impossible because of the speed (dotted quarter = 145).

Comment: According to this [book](https://books.google.es/books?id=7ospDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=spizando&source=bl&ots=uTn3kjNquN&sig=ACfU3U10lhkU6cJaBXQNE-6v2TQzNGdR3w&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_4dj57KTnAhUNz4UKHa_kC9oQ6AEwAnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=spizando&f=false) it means "spiccato", but I don't know how they arrived to this conclusion.

Comment: @11684 you are right. Mine was just a guess.

Comment: @Charo Yes, weird. Spiccato is a bowing technique, which, in absence of a bow, is not available to me. Did you buy this book? Google doesn’t display it for free. If necessary I will gladly pay, [Claude Helffer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Helffer) made an amazing recording of this sonata so he would be a great source since he should have come across this example.

Comment: @11684: No, I don't have this book.

Comment: @11684: Let us know if you discover something.

Comment: @Charo I’m currently pursuing two options. One being Helffer (I know someone who studied with him so maybe he knows what’s up with the weird spiccato) and the other one being [this follow-up question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11486/4692). So far I find spizare being an archaic form of spicciare the most plausible, depending on the answer to my follow-up.