# Until what time was “spizare” in use?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, etymology, history

In response to my first question, [Charo pointed out that spizare is an archaic form of spicciare](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11466/what-does-spizando-mean#comment27112_11466).

Archaic, however, can mean a lot of things; maybe it was in use only before 1600, maybe it was only changed during the past century.

When was spicciare written spizare? More specifically, was spizare still in use in the 1940s?

Comment: Interesting question. To be precise, the abbreviation used by the _Grande dizionario della lingua italian_ is “ant.” = _antico_ (= more or less, ancient). I'd be surprised if they defined “ancient” a form still in use in the last century; it seems to refer to the early centuries of Italian language. Let's hope someone finds some source!

Comment: @DaG Thank you, that nuance was lost to me (I took antico to simply mean “old”).

Comment: That's an interesting question, but I think it will be a very difficult one. Google Books shows some occurrences of "spizare", but not many.

Comment: For instance, it appears in the paper ["La posizione linguistica della Val Rendena"](https://books.google.es/books?id=n4US8xe0gAMC&q=spizare&dq=spizare&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU8YTw_K_nAhVoxYUKHSZ5CUsQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ) (1989) by [Giovanni Bonfadini](http://musicologia.unipv.it/dipartimento/curricula_docenti/Bonfadini.pdf), but probably the author is quoting an old text (I don't know how old).